# How can I retain player orientation after a button is released in C# on Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, transformation

I'm trying to flip a 3D character to get it to face the correct direction that is pressed. So far, my code is working:

```
    private void OrientAvatar()
{
    if (ControlVector.x > DeadZone)
    {
        Spin = -90;
    }

    if (ControlVector.x < DeadZone)
    {

        Spin = 90;
    }

    if (ControlVector.y > DeadZone)
    {

        Spin = 180;
    }

    Pivot.eulerAngles = new Vector3(Pivot.rotation.x, Spin, Pivot.rotation.z);  
}
```

However, when the keys are released it'll flip direction to the opposite. How can I retain the previous orientation set so that the character model remains facing in the correct direction?

Comment: It's likely that the fact that the character flips right back after key release is because of stuff happening in other code you have.  You'll probably have to post more code.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how much more of the code I should post then that. It's a fairly generic controller, nothing special is happening in it besides the 2D flip.

Comment: Where the `OrientAvatar` is called from?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a few minor code corrections:

```
private void OrientAvatar()
{
    Debug.Log(ControlVector.x);

    if (ControlVector.x >= DeadZone)
    {
        Spin = -90;
    }

    if (ControlVector.x <= -DeadZone)
    {
        Spin = 90;

    }

    if (ControlVector.y > DeadZone && Ladder)
    {
        Spin = 180;
    }

    Pivot.eulerAngles = new Vector3(Pivot.rotation.x, Spin, Pivot.rotation.z);  
}
```